# How are WPF Validation Errors Obtained

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've used `INotifyDataErrorInfo` and its predecessor `IDataErrorInfo` for validation of Models/ViewModels.  As part of the validation it was common to give visual feedback via a tooltip or possibly another visual element.  To obtain the validation errors the following binding expression was typically applied:

```
ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"
```

It works and I'm happy about it, but can someone explain this markup?  What is `Validation.Errors`?  Where is it coming from?  I'd like to understand so that I can be appropriately applied and modified future WPF endeavors.  Are there better ways or variants that are more appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Called an [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx), binding syntax is explained in the [relevant property documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx), reading [stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.errors.aspx) helps.